# In a play framework config (hocon), how do I use an environment variable or a default?

Tags: scala, playframework, hocon

In `application.conf`, how do I use a environment variable to set a value, or a default if said environment variable is empty?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
my.value="default"
my.value=${?SOME_ENV_VARIABLE}
```

Play [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ApplicationSecret#environment-variables) explain it very nicely.